# "what(): can't subtract times with different time sources [2 != 1]" error when spawning diff_drive_controller on ros2_control

Tags: ros, diff-drive-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ros2_control to control my robot.
After exectue controller_manager, when I spawned "diff_drive_controller" I have this error.

```
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1632907663.808010997] [controller_manager]: update rate is 50 Hz
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1632907695.226861708] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'diff_drive_controller'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1632907695.255700365] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'diff_drive_controller'
[ros2_control_node-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[ros2_control_node-1]   what():  can't subtract times with different time sources [2 != 1]
```

another terminal shown as

```
$ ros2 control load_controller --set-state start diff_drive_controller
Sucessfully loaded controller diff_drive_controller into state active
```

I tried add parameter `use_sim_time: True` to controller_manager, diff_drive_controller.. but result is same..
How can I solve this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387622/%22what():--can%27t-subtract-times-with-different-time-sources-%5B2-!=-1%5D%22-error-when-spawning-diff_drive_controller-on-ros2_control/) by [byeongkyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4428/byeongkyu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2021-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was solved by updating ros2_control packages.

---

Originally posted by [byeongkyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4428/byeongkyu/) with karma: 126 on 2021-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2021-11-29**:
This should not actually be solved by solely updating the packages. This can still be an issue, depending which time-source is used in a commanding package.

**Comment by [afrixs](https://answers.ros.org/users/37597/afrixs/) on 2021-12-08**:
Building `ros2_control` and (for simulation) `gazebo_ros2_control` from source solved the issue for me too (`diff_drive_controller` can be installed via `apt`)... Crash didn't occur no matter whether `controller_manager spawner` node was launched with `use_sim_time:=True` or `False`. Looks like some kind of incompatibility between packages in current Galactic sync.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

More on this though: we have been working towards resolving this and there's a new batch of safety measures we are planning to add to all velocity-based controllers to ensure the command can time out at *some* point. Different time sources are making this tricky

---

Originally posted by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) with karma: 358 on 2021-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1